# Why I get a null object when I define a new object of that kind

Tags: object, grails

I have a class Item and Animal, everytime I create an Animal I want to 
create a Item on background but when I define the Item object it is null.
I am doing this on Grails Framework

```
 def animalInstance = new Animal(params)
 Item itemInstance = new Item()
 itemInstance.type = 'ANIMAL'
 ItemController itemController = new ItemController()

 itemController.createItem(itemInstance)
```

This is the createItem method, I simplified it to keep it simple

```
def createItem(Item item){

    if(!item.save()){
        redirect action: "create"


    }else{
        redirect action: "show" 
    }
}
```

I do not know why but the `itemInstance` gives me null, and I cannot create the item

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: post the code of itemController.creteItem() method

Comment: How does Item domain look like? Show both the domains, the gsp calling the action as well.

Comment: Why are you doing `ItemController itemController = new ItemController()`

Comment: I agree with Funtik ans James Kleeh, 
I think you should post code for the itemController.creteItem()  method, and also why are you doing this: ItemController itemController = new ItemController() ?
because as I can see it, I think you are trying to access item in your controller and as it is a new instance it is showing the issue or something, more code may help.